# Android: Testing MediaPlayer inside a service

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

In my app, there's a service whose job is to play/stop an audio when it's started. I am using `MediaPlayer` for this.

Service works fine and now I am writing tests for it.
I am using Robolectric's `buildService` method to create the service.
The problem is that `mediaplayer` always comes out to be null in my case.
Here's my service's `onStartCommand` method:

```
@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (ACTION_START.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      try {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.holdmusic);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "not able to prepare media player", e);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_able_prepare_media_player, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
      }
      notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> onStop()); // mediaplayer always comes out to be null here in my test
      mediaPlayer.start();
      mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.app_name));
      showNotification();
      return START_STICKY;
    } else if (ACTION_STOP.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      onStop();
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
    } else {
      // called with unknown action, should not happen
      stopSelf();
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
  }
```

Here's my test:

```
@Test
  public void testActionStart() {
    Intent serviceIntent =
        new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.ACTION_START);

    MediaPlayerService service =
        Robolectric.buildService(MediaPlayerService.class, serviceIntent)
            .create()
            .startCommand(0, 0)
            .get();
    ShadowService shadowService = Shadow.extract(service);

    assertThat(service.isPlaying()).isTrue();
    assertThat(shadowService.getLastForegroundNotification()).isNotNull();
  }
```

Can someone please help me understand why mediaplayer is coming out to be null. I guess maybe because it uses native methods which are not available in robolectric environment. If that's the case,what's the best way to test the service's behaviour?

Comment: might be related to this : https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3855 . will check and update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3855 and debugging for a while, I realised that we have to manually populate the `MediaInfo` object in the `ShadowMediaPlayer` for it to work.

Here's what I did (and it works perfectly now):

Added this line just before instantiating the player:

```
ShadowMediaPlayer.addMediaInfo(
        DataSource.toDataSource(
            "android.resource://"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/"
                + <resource id of audio file>),
        new MediaInfo(17, 0));
```